# Documentation keeps showing old version (readthedocs)

Tags: git, github, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I updated my documentation, I even built it from scratch again and uploaded the corresponding "site" files to github, but no matter what I try, only the oldest version of my doc shows up.
For example, in this [markdown file](https://github.com/johncwok/CategoricalTimeSeries.jl/blob/main/docs/Correlations.md), the example should display

```
data_path = joinpath(dirname(dirname(pathof(CategoricalTimeSeries))), "test", "pewee.txt")
series = readdlm(data_path,',')[1,:]
```

but instead, in the [doc](https://categoricaltimeseriesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Correlations/), this is what appears.

```
series = readdlm("test\\pewee.txt",',')[1,:]
```

At some point while playing with the settings in readthedoc, it work and the correct version was displayed, unfortunately it is back to the old one now and I don't know what I can do to get the correct version.

Comment: It looks like there is the correct version now on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue: I hadn't been using readthedocs for more than one year and in the mean time they made some change in the way the doc is build. Having the .yml from mkdocs is not enough anymore and one should also include a .readthedocs.yml file that specifies that the doc was made with mkdocs (in my case).

Comment: Or, alternatively, configure it in the UI. But using a `.readthedocs.yaml` is the preferred way.